# notify_url no longer working

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-ipn

This has been working for years then about 6 weeks ago or so the notify_url is no longer called, my form/post code looks like this:

```
<form id="payme" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.houdinistop.co.uk/Thanks.aspx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.houdinistop.co.uk/Payment/Receive_PayPal.ashx" />
```

I have a bit of code on the ashx page which will send me an email if the page is hit, and if i go to the ashx page in my browser i get the email, but following a paypal transaction it never calls the handler.

It used to work and I made no changes and now it doesnt work so I'm guessing paypal changes something but all my Googling efforts cant find any info

Comment: If it helps the page that posts this is HTTPS, im not sure if the notify_url should be HTTPS also?

Comment: Ok so i just tested the ashx handler pahe using the IPN test tool on the paypal sandbox and it does work. So I assume it's something I'm doing wrong in this form post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do notify_url setting in bussiness a/c of paypal

In addition to email notification, PayPal can send you the transaction data (also called Instant Payment Notification) to a specific url. With Instant Payment Notification, PayPal sends payment notification messages with encrypted code to the specified URL for each payment you receive. Follow the instructions below to setup Instant Payment Notification.

1. Go to the PayPal website and log in to your account.
2. Click "Profile" at the top of the page.
3. Click "Instant Payment Notification Preferences" in the Selling Preferences column.
4. Click "Edit IPN Settings."
5. Enter the notification URL and select "Receive IPN messages."

   example: http://www.houdinistop.co.uk/Payment/Receive_PayPal.ashx
6. Click "Save."